# Is class number the always the degree of [Hilbert class field of discriminant $D:K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})]$

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, magma

I was going through [https://services.math.duke.edu/~schoen/discriminants.html](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Eschoen/discriminants.html) where the minimal polynomial whose quotient over $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is equal to the Hilbert class field  for discriminants $-23,-31,-44,-59,etc$ is equal to the class number corresponding to the discriminant except for the case where discriminant is $-104$. Why is it not a degree $6$ polynomial?

I went through this code from Pg 47 https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5aff705c5ffd207cc87a512d/t/5bb78d47ec212d427af6dbd0/1538755912894/Class+Field+Theory.pdf but this runs perfectly for $D=-47$ but not for others. Here the degree of minimal polynomial corresponds to [Hilbert class field of discriminant $D: \mathbb{Q}]$.

And for the case of $D=-23$, the polynomial obtained is some random degree $3$ polynomial and does not match with the one on [https://services.math.duke.edu/~schoen/discriminants.html](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Eschoen/discriminants.html)

What is happening in this code? It does not even generate the correct answer for $-27$ or any other discriminant.

```
> R<x> := PolynomialRing(RationalField());
> K<a> := NumberField(x^2 + 47);
> ClassNumber(K);
> L<b> := HilbertClassField(K);
> f<x> := MinimalPolynomial(b,K);
> f;
>L;
```

Comment: $L=K(b)$ doesn't mean that $L=\Bbb{Q}(b)$. The degree of `MinimalPolynomial(b,K)` is equal to `ClassNumber(K)` as told by class field theory. Your question is hard to follow, can you show the problematic code for $-104$?

Comment: @reuns, I am so sorry for the writing. But yes, I meant that ```MinimalPolynomial(b,K)== ClassNumber(K)``` but not for $D=-104$ as I am getting class number $6$ which is correct but minimal polynomial is 
```x^2 + 2``` which is incorrect as it should be degree $6$ polynomial right?

Comment: It's a magma problem, for `K:= NumberField(x^2+26)` then `L<b>:= HilberClassField(K);` doesn't give a primitive element, no idea why. Here you need to try `L<b,c>:= HIlberClassField(K);`  then $L=K(b,c)$ with $[K(b):K]=2,[K(c):3]$ so $[L:K]=6=|Cl(K)|$ as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In magma, instead of

`L<b> := HilberClassField(K);`

try

`L := HilberClassField(K); b := PrimitiveElement(L);`

Then `Degree(MinimalPolynomial(b,K))` is equal to `ClassNumber(K)` as told by class field theory.

Comment: Thank you! Could you also please tell me why in https://services.math.duke.edu/~schoen/discriminants.html they have given minimal polynomial to be  $x^3-x+2$ for $D=-104$?

Comment: It is for a cubic field with discriminant $-104$